# Pandaboard bootup issue

Tags: android, filesystems, bootloader, pandaboard

I have panda board Rev A6. I tried to port JB 4.2.1 on it. But it could not boot up.
If I tried the same thing with my older panda board Rev A4 it works fine. After some googling I come to know that both have different memory. I had made changes accordingly in the kernel and boot loader. After those changes Kernel boot starts but when it tries to up Android FS it stuck. Nothing comes with serial console.

Any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

This is step for per-built installation of linaro-Android on panda board. I also port Android on panda board Rev A6 and this work for me.

1. Download these three files from
   https://releases.linaro.org/13.04/Android/panda

   1. Boot.tar.bz2
   2. System.tar.bz2
   3. Userdata.tar.bz2
      and put into one directory(LIKE pandroid).
2. Install linaro-image-tools and the tip of linaro-image-tools

   ```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa: linaro-maintainers/tools
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get install linaro-image-tools
   ```
3. Create Sd-card
   3.1 Inser SD-card on your computer.
   3.2 Check By : dmesg
       it so like sdb or sdc connect.
   3.3 Fromat Sd-card from disk Utility.
   3.4 Run linaro image tools from

   ```
   $ linaro-android-media-create --mmc /dev/sdc --dev panda --boot boot.tar.bz2 --system system.tar.bz2 --userdata userdata.tar.bz2
   ```

   Here from pandroid directory.

   *NOTICE* Here change /dev/sdb if it show in dmesg command : sdb.
4. After running this command we have to Install graphics libraries

   ```
   $ wget http://people.linaro.org/~vishalbhoj/install-binaries-4.0.4.sh
   $ chmod a+x install-binaries-4.0.4.sh
   $ ./install-binaries-4.0.4.sh /dev/sdb2 (system partition).

   *NOTICE*: Here change /dev/sdb if it shows in dmesg command : sdb.
   ```
5. Insert card in pandaboard & connect to your computer.
   check by command : `dmesg`.
   it show ttyUSB0
6. Start minicom:`sudo minicom -s`

   6.1 set port : ttyUSB0

   6.2 Save setup as Default.

   6.3 Exit.
7. Start pandaboard.